# ARM template - deploy multiple WebApps

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I would like to deploy several web applications to one Azure App Service to dedicated Virtual directories. For example:

WebApp1 to site\wwwroot\app1

WebApp2 to site\wwwroot\app2

How can I do this using Azure Resource Manager Template??

Answer (score 1):

Your ARM template for Azure Web App on dedicated virtual directory should look like below:

```
   {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "parameters('WebApp1')",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
       ...
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "config",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('WebApp1'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {

            "virtualApplications": [
              {
                "virtualPath": "/",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot"
              },
              {
                "virtualPath": "/WebApp1",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot\\app1"
              },
            ]
          }
        }
    }
```

You can also reference to this [complete sample ARM template](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/aa75b8a5780dfb81b5ae47624958884c324e4aa0/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json#L71-L80).

Hope this helps!